# How do I set up recurring donations with Stripe?

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, recurring-contributions, stripe

Im operating in Drupal 7 with Civi 4.7.30 and the latest Stripe API.

I want to set up recurring donations but it keeps giving me errors. I have it enabled on the Contribution page.

In Stripe they said to set up "Subscriptions" Which I did in the form of recurring donations. This does not enable the recurring to happen.

Advise on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue, not sure if it's the same but I applied this patch to correct:

https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/pull/249/files